# How to establish connection from a rake task?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, oracle, rake

I need to create a rake task that gets the table rows from a MySQL database, parse the data, and insert into an Oracle database. The databases are on two different hosts.

My current attempt:

```
namespace :import_from_mysql do
  class MySQLConnection < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.abstract_class = true
    establish_connection({
    :adapter  => 'mysql',
    :host     => 'xxx.xxx.com',
    :database => 'sample_database',
    :username => 'username',
    :password => 'password'
    })
  end

  class MySQLTable < MySQLConnection
    self.table_name = "users"
    self.primary_key = "id"
    self.inheritance_column = "something_unique_here"
  end

  desc "Parse data before inserting to oracle database"
  task :insert_to_oracle => :environment do |t|
    puts "Rake task has begun...\n\n"
    puts "Parsing data from MYSQL...\n\n"

    MySQLTable.establish_connection

    puts "Rake task has completed!"
  end
end
```

But the **MySQLTable.establish_connection** establishes a connection to my local database which is sqlite even though I'm trying to connect to a mysql_adapter.

When I tried to establish a connection using the command below, I was able to connect to a MySQL adapter but I don't know how I can access my tables after the connection was established:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection({:adapter => "mysql", :database => "sample_database", :host => "xxx.xxx.com", :username => "username", :password => "password" })
```

Any idea on why it keeps on connecting to sqlite? And after successfully establishing a connection to mysql, how do I select table rows after the MySQLTable.establish_connection statement?

Comment: do you intend to use one of active record models for querying?

Comment: It is better if I can just directly execute the sql command. @adamliesko

Comment: then, see the answer below

Answer (score 2):

You can use mysql2 gem (https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2) inside your rake task.

```
client = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "localhost", :username => "username", :database => "sample_database", :password => "password")
users = client.query("SELECT * FROM users")
```

Comment: Another thing, I changed the adapter in MySQLConnection class to 'mysql2'. But when I removed the class the code above doesn't work anymore. It says NameError: uninitialized constant Mysql2

Comment: I removed the MySQLConnection class since the configuration for the connection is already defined in Mysql2::Client.new(...)

Answer (score 2):

With the connection generated using ActiveRecord::Base you can execute SQL statements against whatever database you connect to. Like so:

```
connection = ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  :adapter  => "mysql",
  :host     => "faraway",
  :username => "myuser",
  :password => "mypass",
  :database => "somedatabase"
)
connection.execute('SELECT * FROM users')
```

Once established, the connection can also be referenced from ActiveRecord::Base class.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(...)
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(...)
```

Comment: I got NoMethodError: undefined method `execute' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool:0x00000107a9c8d0>

Comment: Tried to do connection.connection.execute('SELECT * FROM symbol_events') the it says NoMethodError: undefined method `init' for Mysql:Class. What could I possibly be missing?

Comment: I'm positive that my connection is correct. But I don't know what to do with this undefined method `init' for Mysql:Class.

Answer (score 1):

Thought it might be helpful for someone else. The following worked for me!

```
connection = ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  :adapter  => "mysql",
  :host     => "faraway",
  :username => "myuser",
  :password => "mypass",
  :database => "somedatabase"
)

@connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
result = @connection.exec_query('SELECT * FROM users')

result.each do |row|
puts row
end
```

Here, users is an already existing table in the "somedatabase".

Answer (score 1):

although I am a noob with connections and "database back office" my trivial approach works like a charm, and there is no need with parameters in rake task that is for updating "domain tables" that contain only defining data like legal or help texts:

```
pre_db = ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection('preproduction').connection

prod_db = ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection('online').connection
```

and in `database.yml` I defined the databases. ("preproduction" is a step between dev and prod in my case and a real environment like "development". where 'online' is almost the same as 'production' (I made a different entry only for security reasons - not to destroy production if `database.yml` gets uploaded)